# Normal Dialog or Bottom Sheet dialog for confirmation

Tags: android, mobile-application, material-design, dialog

I am about to pick dialog type for confirmation (yes, no) when deleting an item.
I have two options to choose from:

1. Bottom sheet dialog
2. Normal dialog

What is the best for this scenario and why?

**Context:** Android app using Material Design

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on the importance you want to give an action. I think it would be best to use normal dialog in that case.

This way you will get the user to focus on the task of answering yes or no.

Do not forget that offering as options yes / no is not correct, because you force the user to read the message.

Comment: why do you think bottom sheet dialog not suitable? what options should I give, if it is not yes/no? edit your answer to answer this. so I could accept

Answer (score 1):

Undo for deletion is by far more productive and less painful UX, consider using it. E.g. Snackbar with an Undo button. Deleting multiple items when there is a god-awful popup is some of the most cringe-worthy UX possible.

How can one argue that Bottom Sheet is better than a Dialog? If it is easier to confirm/reject the Bottom Sheet than it is to do the same with the Dialog then you could say it is better, from a usability perspective. However that still depends on the nature of the change. If deletion is final and could cause a great impact to the User, other people, or systems then perhaps it is wiser to make it harder to confirm/reject.

Confirming/rejecting Dialogs is hard because the Dialog is invasive to content and usability (modal and in the middle of content) and the buttons are placed somewhere in the middle of the screen (not the easiest places to click with a mouse nor a finger). Bottom Sheet can at least expose buttons at the bottom corners of the screen which is much easier for mouse and finger interaction.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Question does not ask anything about a bottom navigation.

Comment: undo idea is good. why you think deleting multiple items with a dialog problematic? when all items will be deleted with one dialog, where a message is shown with number of items to be deleted.

Comment: undo is good idea. why you think deleting multiple items with a dialog is problematic? when all selected items are deleted at once and a message with number of items to be deleted is shown.

Comment: Problem with the bottom sheet is when user tapped on the desired action icon from the top action bar, user have to move the finger to the bottom in order to do the confirmation, which is bad according to Fitt's law

Comment: You are assuming that the User used their finger to interact, or even then assuming they use only one finger to interact. So Fitt's Law can be calculated multiple times across the various means of interaction, the total result can then be considered and factored into an assessment of time, cost, and benefit in deciding whether to continue research & development or accept the current state.

Comment: If you are allowing multiple selection in a list and then using the Dialog, that isn't too bad. I was recalling my experience with Sony phones whereby the gallery uses a Dialog to confirm for each single image (no multiple selection possible).