# bottom sheet dialog or complete screen for new task

Tags: android, mobile-application, material-design, dialog

I am developing something similar to a task app.
For new task screens there are two approaches to go with

1. Bottom sheet dialog like in [Google Tasks](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/YULB7Yf19JjPbDGJjh-WiBSbdNDTtxjaDu8bUkLb3xYyuMqM1ifom9qXdInfN18TQhA=w720-h310-rw), [Todoist](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/OQNZcANY8YLT0YaBtj4BbBWvZbCBvSJSMFjuQMoIDM1SmukmqAnvTI_oeeSFqWVMZzBB=w1366-h700-rw)
2. Complete screen with items laid out vertically.

Todoist has a natural language understanding capabilities and supports both of these approaches while giving priority to the bottom-sheet app.
Google Tasks app only supports bottom-sheet approach for new tasks.

The thing I cannot understand is **Why give priority to bottom-sheet approach? What is so user friendly about it?**
If you see Todoist's new task screen, buttons are small and tightly packed, yes it has natural language understanding capabilities, so you could type things in text.

New approaches with better UX for new task screen are also welcome!

Comment: The links don't work. Could you please add screenshots instead?

Comment: If the task can be managed in the bottom part of the screen then there is an added advantage of being operated by single hand.

Comment: @Ren It does work. Anyway Google Play  links: [Google Tasks first slide](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.tasks) , [Todoist first slide](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.todoist)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main point about it is the **retention of context** for the given sub-task. You have a main task and a sub-task, sometimes an interaction with both is necessary in parallel. The bottom sheet presents the sub-task while the **main context** is still visible, so as to aid the user's mental flow.

Here are a two examples.

---

### Maps

The best example is Google Maps (or anything similar). Imagine having to switch between screens constantly. The advantage here is simultaneous interaction with two screens.

[image]

---

### Google Drive

In this case it helps the user remember where he is about to upload his new file. Maybe he made a mistake and chose the wrong folder, this way he can still spot it while in the process.

[image]

---

Your example of Todoist is definitely debatable, as it seems cramped and too small. We can only guess why they used it, maybe wanted to go with "cool" new tech? Who knows.

**But the point is that the bottom sheet definitely has its UX advantages for specific kinds of tasks.**

---

**Edit:**  In response to the question in the comments

> *Does it make sense for my case?*

As long as it really offers an advantage (e.g. in terms of context or error prevention), it would be a good idea. Though, one should be careful to not introduce unexpected disadvantages with this functionality; meaning to think through the standard user flow and see where it helps or hinders the user (weight **advantages vs disadvantages**).

For example the screenshot of Todoist makes it look very cramped and too small, where I would assume the advantage of context is somewhat damaged by the (presumably) bad UX.

Comment: Even Google Tasks use the bottom sheet. Using bottom sheet in contextual context make sense. Does it make sense for my case (showing existing tasks behind, may be to avoid duplicating tasks) while tightly packing things up?

Comment: @user158 I would assume so, especially when both of these big apps employ it too, it seems to offer something useful. I would just be careful to make it usable and not too cramped and small like Todoist. Try to think if it brings with it any disadvantage in the normal user flow and weight it up against the advantage of context, it may or may not be worth it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. add your comment to the answer so the answer will be complete. So I could accept the answer.

Comment: @user158 No problem, I added a bit more to my answer :)

Comment: Thanks. You may also answer my other questions: [more options menu](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/125939/how-to-decide-to-what-should-go-in-more-options-menu), [dark action bar](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/127988/white-action-bar-or-dark-actionbar), [bottom sheet vs normal dialog](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/129091/normal-dialog-or-bottom-sheet-dialog-for-confirmation)